# php replace %20

Tags: php, sql

i curently try to make a search for my system using $_GET
so when user copy the address link of results http://localhost/search?q=iphone%204

how to replce %20 to use + and for same time,when query the sql,it will search for 'iphone 4' not 'iphone+4' .

any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) to encode. The decoding will happen automatically, you just need to read the value from `$_GET`.

Answer (score 6):

To replace %20 with +

```
$url = str_replace("%20", "+", $url);
```

To change the plus into a space for your queries:

```
$url = urldecode($url);
```

Comment: `%20` and `+` both map to a space after `urldecode()` anyway, so the first step would be unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

encode your "+" using "%2B".
or use rawurldecode instead of urldecode. If that's not what you need than please supply some code so I can be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to decode it if you just use the `$_GET` array: http://ca.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

If you use the link you mentioned, you can access the query using `echo $_GET['q']` will result in `iphone 4`, then you can use `explode(' ', $_GET['q'])` which will result in `array('iphone', '4')`.